# Who is the creator or inventor of coefficient of determination (R-squared)?

Tags: history

Who is the creator or inventor of coefficient of determination (R-squared) ?

I know that Galton invented correlation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A search on JSTOR shows that this term became quickly and widely adopted in the 1920s. It has been attributed to

Wright, Sewall. 1921. Correlation and causation. *Journal of Agricultural Research* 20: 557-585.

Wright was one of the giants of 20th century evolutionary biology.

For a rough but readable copy online, see [here](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/soc/class/soc952/Wright/Wright_Correlation%20and%20Causation.pdf)

Comment: Which words do you put in JSTOR? I cannot find the result by searching? THANKS

Comment: I searched for `"coefficient of determination"` (including quotation marks) and then looked at early references.

Comment: I do not know why I cannot get the same results after searching for "coefficient of determination" and pressing "Oldest", but thank you.

Comment: As I said, I looked at references in what came up. I didn't say that this Wright paper is on JSTOR, as it isn't.

Comment: (+1) I was performing a similar search recently.  Although I didn't find Wright's paper directly, I easily came upon Bradford Smith's *Forecasting the Acreage of Cotton* in JASA (1925).  Smith quotes Wright in a lengthy footnote and credits him with inventing the term.